# Older laptop stuck in low-power state on Windows boot

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu, power-management

I'm currently servicing an about 10 year old Packard Bell Easynote MX45 which I upgraded with a SSD and Windows 10 (Windows 7 and Vista before).

The issue is that the CPU doesn't clock up when Windows boots and is stuck in its lowest power state at 230 *MHz*. It's impossible to use the laptop in that state, logging in takes about 5 minutes, starting the Task-Manager another 5 for example. The only way to resolve the issue is the program [Throttlestop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) which immediately forces the CPU to clock up and stay at the usual 2 GHz. However this doesn't work at login-time since it seems to have issues when trying to autostart it via task scheduler (stays in background and doesn't do anything), so I'm stuck starting it when the Desktop finally shows and manage to start it (after ~10 Minutes).

I checked the following things:

- There are no power related settings in the BIOS. No Speedstep settings, nothing. BIOS is up-to-date.
- Windows power plan is on High Performance
- All drivers are installed, Intel chipset drivers current. Windows is updated.
- No heat issues
- No physical Eco-mode switches or similar are activated

Anything else I can do/check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an acceptable workaround I've used [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) (Non-Sucking Service Manager) to install a service for Throttlestop. My previous tries didn't work because the .exe wasn't a service executable.

I just installed it with `nssm install fixcputhrottle`, put in the path to the throttlestop.exe and restarted. It doesn't take effect on the login screen but a few seconds after the user has logged it clocks up which is satisfactory in my case.